# YA novel ID: library monster, post-apocalyptic, ELECTRICITY sign

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, post-apocalyptic

I would like to identify a young-adult SF novel I read in the early-mid 1990s. My fragmentary memories are:

- I think the protags were children (probably two children, maybe boy and girl).
- They were in some kind of post-apocalyptic future.
- They were, I think, initially in a buried library or something, before they got out.
- There was a pretty mysterious hint of some kind of "monster", not an evil bad thing, but rather a creature that was just *there* -- this is mainly why the memory intrigues me.
- When they went out into the devastated real world, they found a sign that spelled ELECTRICITY but with some letters missing. There was a scene with the protags wondering "what does TRITY mean?" or some such.

First post here but I have loved sci-fi all my life. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you happen to recall any details of the cover?  Was it paperback or hardcover?  How thick was it?

Comment: Thanks David: but I don't remember that at all. It was recommended to me from the school library (secondary school, probably about 1993) by the English teacher. They had loads of YA SF stuff, mostly shorts collections. but this one was a full novel, I think -- probably hardcover 'cause most of the library books were. (And I hope I'm not mixing up 2 different books.)

Comment: Possibly a fool's errand, but could you contact your English teacher or school library?

Comment: No. It was 1993. They're all dead. We are the post-apocalyptic kids in the library now.

Comment: Look here, if anything looks familiar: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/AfterTheEnd/Literature

Comment: ^_^ We're not *that* old, but indeed, the odds of a librarian remembering a book you read two decades ago, unless it was one very dear to them, is a bit remote. Do you remember if the kids interacted with anyone other than the monster? Was it defined what caused the apocalypse? Was the library initially buried, buried under the rubble, housing a fallout shelter? Had the apocalypse just happened, or were they just now escaping?

Comment: Unfortunately I really posted all that I remembered. But to your last question: I think the apocalypse was long ago; nobody else was around, and significant time passed before they got out of the buried place. However, as a dream-diarist I am well aware that if you think about these details too much, you can start inventing things that weren't there. Thanks everybody for your help so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be *[Why Weeps the Brogan?](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/865004.Why_Weeps_the_Brogan_)*, by Hugh Scott. It's been a while since I read it, and I can't put my hands on a copy right now, but it is about a sister and brother who are trapped in a museum. There has been an apocalyptic event and something they call The Brogan is too scary to get past.

Sorry, I can't remember the resolution, but the reviews and book covers on Goodreads may help jog your memory.

(The Brogan turns out to be

> the children's mother, who has been horribly deformed & seems not to be able to speak, but was keeping them inside and safe.)

Comment: Ahh, yes, the title rings a bell, and it was published in 1991!